# PGL(2,c) is isomorphic to PSL(2,c)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Definition: Projective special linear group
>
> $PSL\left ( n,\mathbb{F} \right )=\frac{SL\left ( n,\mathbb{F} \right )}
> {\left ( Z\left ( GL\left ( n,\mathbb{F} \right ) \right )\cap SL\left ( n,\mathbb{F} \right ) \right )}$

Proof:

> Let $A \in GL\left ( 2,\mathbb{C} \right )$ and let >$\lambda=\sqrt{det\left ( A \right )^{-1}}\in\mathbb{C}$
>
> Then, $det\left ( \left ( \lambda I \right )A \right )=det\left ( \lambda I \right )det\left ( A \right )=\lambda^{2}det\left ( A \right )=1$
>
> So, $\lambda A=SL\left ( 2,\mathbb{C} \right )$.
>
> Since $A =\left ( \lambda^{-1} I \right )\left ( \lambda A \right )$
>
> we have
>
> $\mathbf{\left ( 1 \right )}$
>
> $\mathbf{
> GL\left ( 2,\mathbb{C} \right )=SL\left ( 2,\mathbb{C} \right )Z\left ( GL\left ( 2,\mathbb{C} \right ) \right )}$
>
> and so,
>
> $\mathbf{\left ( 2 \right )}$
>
> $\mathbf{PGL\left ( 2,\mathbb{C} \right )=PSL\left ( 2,\mathbb{C} \right )}$

Why is every matrices in GL the product of some matrices in SL and in the center of the group GL?
(1) and (2) in bold is not very clear to me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first one is because the center of $GL_n$ precisely consists of the scalar matrices. The second is because of one of the isomorphism theorems.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I don't quite understand how "factoring out" Z from SL gives PSL. Could you explain?

Comment: I am not sure which part you are asking about. By definition $PSL$ is the quotient of $SL$ by its center.

Comment: Point (2) is the question I am asking. 
What I meant was how does "factoring out" SL(2,C)Z gives SL/Z?@TobiasKildetoft

Comment: As I said, that is one of the isomorphism theorems $HN/N\cong H/(H\cap N)$.

Comment: How silly of me. By the second Isomorphism. @TobiasKildetoft Thanks!