# Is mobius groups isomorphic to PSL(2,C) or PGL(2,C)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

I'm looking at the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) on Mobius group. But I didn't get if this group is isomorphic to $PSL(2, \mathbb{C})$ or to $PGL(2, \mathbb{C})$

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1772304/pgl2-c-is-isomorphic-to-psl2-c), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1576005/on-the-relation-between-psl2-mathbb-f-and-pgl2-mathbb-f?rq=1).

Comment: [This duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121619/why-does-psl2-mathbb-c-cong-pgl2-mathbb-c-but-psl2-mathbb-r-not-con?noredirect=1&lq=1) is better, I am sorry. I don't know how to change this.